# Having an issue converting pandas dataframe 'object' column into a float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

I am trying to convert 2 columns in a pandas dataframe into float values as they are currently listed as 'object'. When I try to convert using .astype() the one column is then placed with value 0 instead of the original numbers and the second converts to float but removes the digits after the decimal places. I need to perform some calculations and need the data as a float.

I have the original dataframe with 2 columns: price and qty

```
          price               qty
0    0.00080000   157523.03870305
1    0.00080300    75173.00864078
2    0.00080450    67683.65347307
3    0.00082162    14939.84800485
4    0.00082300    47508.48349310
5    0.00085000    20000.00000000

price    object
qty      object
```

When I try converting with .astype() the price column returns 0 and qty removes the decimal points:

```
     price     qty
0        0  157523
1        0   75173
2        0   67684
3        0   14940
4        0   47508
5        0   20000

price      float64
qty        float64
```

Here's the code:

```py
df['price'] = df['price'].astype(float)
bid['qty'] = bid['qty'].astype(float)
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

Expected Output:

```
          price               qty
0    0.00080000   157523.03870305
1    0.00080300    75173.00864078
2    0.00080450    67683.65347307
3    0.00082162    14939.84800485
4    0.00082300    47508.48349310
5    0.00085000    20000.00000000

price      float64
qty        float64
```

Comment: Did you set before how pandas format the floats? Try to do `pd.options.display.float_format = "{:.8f}".format` at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the columns into numeric using `pd.to_numeric()` before converting them to float as all your columns are of `object` dtype. Depending on the data supplied, it (`pd.to_numeric()`) automatically returns `float64` or `int64`. More details are provided in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html)

By adding `errors=coerce` you can replace the errors with `NaN`.

Here is how you can do it

```
import pandas as pd

# Replicating the same data as provided
data = {
    'price': ['0.00080000', '0.00080300', '0.00080450', '0.00082162', '0.00082300', '0.00085000'],
    'qty': ['157523.03870305', '75173.00864078', '67683.65347307', '14939.84800485', '47508.48349310', '20000.00000000']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert the columns to float using pd.to_numeric()
df['price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['price'], errors='coerce')
df['qty'] = pd.to_numeric(df['qty'], errors='coerce')

print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

which results in output that you desired.

```
price            qty
 0  0.000800  157523.038703
 1  0.000803   75173.008641
 2  0.000804   67683.653473
 3  0.000822   14939.848005
 4  0.000823   47508.483493
 5  0.000850   20000.000000

price    float64
qty      float64
```